# react-native packet doesn't implement method from supertype. Error after framework upgrade. What to do now?

Tags: react-native

I've upgraded my react-native project with react-native-git-upgrade

Now, one of the modules I'm using throws this error:

```
/Users/alex/Code/AwesomeApp/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceInfo.java:26: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
1 error
:react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

So this was one of my general concerns about react-native: Having to use all these immature npm packets is a risky business. For some reason unknown to me, this one (RNDeviceInfo) doesn't work anymore after the framework update.

So what's the right thing to do here? Fix the packet myself? Get rid of the module rewrite my whole app? Continue working with an old react-native version?

Comment: apparently it is not only RNDeviceInfo but most other NPM packages including react-native-maps and my own implementations of native modules. Updating the NPM packages did not help. Removing the @Override annotation worked out fine but does not give me confidence of having good code under my hands. I will post this as an answer if no better solutions will be posted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Checking package.json it turned out not all libraries were up to date. The abovementioned react-native-device-info was actually updated but the version number wasn't incremented.

Comment: the version of react-native-device-info in package.json is *0.10.2*. What to do with it ?

Comment: use this: "^0.11.0". That's the newest version. Edit: The caret will make sure to update the major versions of this packet